# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Unable to resolve this issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, path

I am getting this error. I tried all the combinations of the paths of directories but every time I am getting following errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/myapp/dist/styles.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/myapp/styles/branding.css 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/myapp/dist/styles.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:3000/myapp/styles/branding.css
```

I have made an index.html which is requesting swaggerindex.html in which following scripts and stylesheets are present.

- bundle.js
- branding.js
- styles.css
- branding.css

Here is the code snippet of swaggerindex.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../myapp/dist/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../myapp/styles/branding.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Sending the content from swagger index</p>
    <div class="total-wrapper" ui-view></div>
    <script src="../myapp/dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="../myapp/scripts/branding.js"></script>
```

Here is the screenshot of the directory structure

```
myapp
  |--index.html
  |--swaggerindex.html
  |--dist //directory containing styles.css and bundle.js
       |--styles.css
       |--bundle.js
  |--scripts //directory 
       |--branding.js
  |--styles //directory
       |--branding.css
```

for more clarification of directory structure you can visit to
[github link of the directory structure](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor)

**Note:** This doesnot contain dist folder but it is created when we build it in local machine

**Note:** I have changed the name of index.html file to swaggerindex.html

Comment: Try: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles.css">`

Comment: @Hackerman I tired it also.. but it is not working

Comment: No Sir it is not working. I have tried it earlier but still same error comes up in the console @Hackerman

Answer (score 0):

`..` will go to parent folder.

Hope this will be useful

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../myapp/styles/branding.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Sending the content from swagger index</p>
    <div class="total-wrapper" ui-view></div>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/branding.js"></script>
```

Comment: No Sir it is not working. I have tried all the possible combinations but still it is not working. @user2181397

Answer (score 0):

Inside the root folder of your angular2 project, note the naming, it has to be in this form "project-name"

Step1: ng install
Step2: ng build --prod
Step3: step2 will produce a "dist" folder inside your project's root directory
Step4: go inside "dist" folder, and take note of the full path
Step5: create a VHOST like this:
 
    ServerAdmin someone@somewhere.com
    DocumentRoot "full\path\to\dist\directory"
    ServerName projectname

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /enterprise-sa/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/enterprise-sa/
ProxyPassReverse /enterprise-sa/ http://127.0.0.1:8001/enterprise-sa/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Step6: add an entry in /etc/hosts file
       XXX.X.X.X  projectname

restart apache/nginx